# Bus error 10 with assembly code + general questions

Tags: c, assembly, bus

Okay so I'm trying to create a program for fun which counts the bits in a number

**What I Want:**
As I said, a program which counts the bits in a given number.
(for instance countsbits(1)=countbits(2)=countbits(4)=1).

**What I Get:**
I get the correct output but now I receive an error message

"Segmentation fault:11". I ran someone else's program and they did not receive this error, so clearly it's my wrongdoing. How can I amend this so I don't get a segmentation fault?

The command I enter is:

```
gcc -m32 -mstackrealign countbit.c countbits.s
```

The program compiles just fine but when I try to run the a.out generated by the program I get the error. Any ideas?

My Code:
    .text
        .data
        .globl _x

```
    .globl _countbits
_countbits:

    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    pushl %ebx
    mov $0,%edx
    mov $0,%eax
    mov 8(%ebp),%ebx

LOOP:
    mov $1,%ecx
    and %ebx,%ecx
    add %ecx,%eax
    shrl $1,%ebx
    add $1,%edx
    cmp $32,%edx
    jle LOOP
    pop %ebx
    pop %ebp
    ret
```

and the code that calls it from C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo (int x){
  int p=countbits(x);
  printf("The count is: %d",p);
}

main(){
  int x=16;
  foo(16);
}
```

Comment: A cursory glance suggests that you switched the order in which you pop `ebx` and `ebp`.

Comment: this worked. Thanks very much, but now I receive a segmentation fault. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Load up the core dump into the debugger and see what instruction is taking the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really ask a question about assembly code without mentioning what kind of processor assembly code you're talking about.  For example, many processors have a dedicated instruction for counting number of bits set.  For example, see [POPCNT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT)